# Trying to predict values in a column using a model in R

Tags: r, dataframe, model, prediction, gam

I'll state up front that I have little experience in R, and really appreciate any help folks can provide.

I have a data frame (I think) of values:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwsSB.png)

I am trying to predict each value of the "PredBFwdth" column, using a model I've created from other data and the values of "ThatwgFAC" and "ThalwgSlop".

The name of the model is "Model"; it is a generalized additive model, so I would be using predict.gam.  I thought the code would look something like:

```
PredBFwdth = predict.gam(Model, ThalwgFAC, ThalwgSlop)
```

This doesn't work, obviously.  I'll need to make predictions for every row in the data, using corresponding values from the ThalwgFAC and ThalwgSlop columns and the model.  Can someone assist?  I've poked around looking for answers, but the code on other folks questions is indecipherable to me.  :(

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend giving enough data and code to create a reproducible example. That means a sample of what your data could look like and what code you are trying in order to facilitate help.

First I'll start with some fake data that is in a data.frame

```
dat <- data.frame(

ThalwgFAC = rnorm(100,3,5),
ThalwgSlop = rnorm(100,3,2),
ThalwgEv = rnorm(100,2,2)
)
```

Next, you fit your model

```
library(mgcv)

fit <- gam(ThalwgEv ~ s(ThalwgFAC) + s(ThalwgSlop), data = dat)
```

Now to your question about predicting new data, you can just feed the new data (as a data frame) to the `predict` function and specify which model you are going to use (the `fit` object from above). This presumes the data frame contains the same variable names that were used for the model (e.g. ThalwgFAC and ThalwgSlop).

```
dat2 <- data.frame(
  
  ThalwgFAC = rnorm(100,3,5),
  ThalwgSlop = rnorm(100,3,2),
  ThalwgEv = rnorm(100,2,2)
)

pred <- predict(fit, newdata = dat2)
```

The `predict` function will pick up the class of the `fit` object, so no need to specify the method to use (i.e. predict.gam).